# How to make imagebutton and textview to be clicked together in android?

Tags: android, selector, imagebutton

I have ImageButton and TextView inside RelativeLayout.
I want to change their colors to blue when they are pressed and make them white again when released. also I need to do it to both of them no matter which of them I click.
and I want to activate the same action to both of them, for example a Toast that will be shown on the screen.

I tried to do it using selectors and duplicateParentState and many other options.
Can someone give me a simple example of how to do it?

**UPDATE:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/trash_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/trash_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/trash"/>
</selector>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#33B5E5" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#33B5E5" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

and this is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_ResetData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/reset_button_selector"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/button_ResetData"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/Button_ResetData"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:textColor="@drawable/main_buttons_text_color_selector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I click the layout the selectors of the text and button is activated but not the click event. when I click the button the selectors don't work but the click event works

Comment: Can you post your current code so we can help you more accurately?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FOUND A SOLUTION:

```
final ImageButton resetButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ResetData);
            final TextView resetButton_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_button_ResetData_title);
            View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener_ResetButton = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            resetButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trash_pressed);
                            resetButton_Title.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue_Light));
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            resetButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.trash);
                            resetButton_Title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to clear the list (except \"In progress\")?")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", resetListDialogClickListener)
                                    .setNegativeButton("No", resetListDialogClickListener);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
                            TextView messageView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                            messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            };
            resetButton.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener_ResetButton);
            resetButton_Title.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener_ResetButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set selectors to RelativeLayout directly and implement [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) for the same. And make sure you include `android:clickable="true"` inside your RelativeLayout.

Comment: I don't understand this...why would I need selectors in the layout when I want to change the color of the image and the text?

I don't want to set onClick for the layout cause the layout is bigger than the button and text (weight = 1).

Answer (score 1):

**Very Simple**

In your activity where u call the on click function... define them separately but use them like this

```
public class yourclass extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{


    ImageButton IMGBTN1;

      TextView tv1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_previousentry);


        IMGBTN1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);       

        IMGBTN1.setOnClickListener(this);
                tv1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
 public void onClick(View v) 

          {



                if (v == IMGBTN1 )
                               {
                IMGBTN1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"img 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  delay();

                                }
                                if (v == tv1)
                               {
             IMGBTN1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"textview 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         delay();

                                }


      public void delay()
   {
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                  IMGBTN1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
              tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

              }

        }, 500);

   }
    }
```

Comment: I EDITED CODE PLS CHECK

Comment: what about the selectors?

Comment: and if u want the button to have default color after click then i will update the code further

Comment: bcoz this will change the color but not reset to default

Comment: Updated it further and this will solve all your issue , glad to help

Comment: its actually very simple

Comment: u can use selector class... but if u have to it programitically. i think this is the answer... and what you have asked can be only answered in a way something like this

Comment: happy coding... you can try other answers

Comment: if u dont consider it as an answer vote it up.. so that other can review and help

Comment: their is a delay between the views
I press the button it become blue and after a second the text become blue I want them both to become blue at the same time

I want to click one and both of them become blue

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourView.performClick()` to programatically click a  button.

Comment: if your click event is detected and the selector doesnt trigger on the ImageButton then you should change       android:src="@drawable/reset_button_selector" to   android:background="@drawable/reset_button_selector"

Comment: The selector doesn't trigger on the imagebutton and the textview

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

Add selectors to both Textview and image drawable. Add that image drawable to textview using attributes like drawableLeft, drawableTop etc in xml.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can I scale size that drawable left using xml?

Comment: Do you want animation separately for that image ?

Comment: I'm not talking about animation
The picture is too big for the space I have so I want to make it smaller but I can't control its size if I put it in the backgorund